Wordpress plugins not working inside a container
Lately, I've been trying to Dockerize my Wordpress instance using 3 containers, one for nginx, another for mariadb and one for Wordpress itself. But I simply can't get it to work. For starters, every time Wordpress has to call any plugin function it throws:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Besides, I can't access some pages, for example if I try to access the index.php page I get page not found. However, I can access some pages directly, like wp-login.php.
Here is Nginx container:

Here is my Wordpress container:

My docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  wp_db:
    build: ./db
    container_name: db_wp
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  
  wp:
    depends_on:
      - wp_db
    image: wordpress:6.2.1-fpm-alpine
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html
  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wp
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./wp:/var/www/html

Here is my nginx.conf file:
 server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  access_log off;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;
  server_tokens off;
  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  location /wp-admin {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
          try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-admin/index.php?$args;
    }
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on wordpress:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}

I tried changing ownership and permissions, but it still doesn't work.

Maybe you need to check the include paths.

but the instance works outside of the container, so the include paths have to be correct

A call to a undefined funtion would tell, there is something missing. Can you dig the logs what function call is missing to investigate further?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function the_ad_group() in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/entrance-child/wrapper-start.php:11. This function comes from the advanced-ads plugin, the thing is, before this error there was another Call to undefined function related to another plugin, but as I was already thinking about removing it, I replaced the functions with Wordpress native functions. So, my conclusion was that Wordpress is not able call any plugin function when it is inside a container.
